# Neural Networks in RStudio

Tags: r, neural-network

I am trying to predict the variable price range which has 4 levels (0,1,2,3) with the neural network.
But the table with the results just have 2 lines, instead of 4.
I don't know why the table is not 4x4.
The idx only has ones and fours. And the pred only has 0 and 3.
Sometimes the table has 3 lines, but never 4. And most of the times has only 2.
Please help.
THAANK YOUU

```
#install.packages("rJava")
library(rJava)
#install.packages("xlsx")
library(xlsx)

#Read file of dataToModelset
setwd("C:/Users/Utilizador/Desktop/AE")
dataread <- read.xlsx("datasetDeleteOutliers.xlsx",1)


dataread <-datasetDeleteOutliers
dataread <-datasetCorrelation
dataread <-datasetMedian
dataread <-datasetNearestNeighbor
#

data <- data.frame(dataread)
str(data)


data$clock_speed=as.numeric(data$clock_speed)
data$m_dep=as.numeric(data$m_dep)
str(data)

# Search for binary variables
is_binary <- function(x) length(unique(x)) == 2
sapply(data, is_binary)
summary(data)#para ver o resumo das carateristicas dos dados

#data normalization
#z_score_function <- function(y) {(y - mean(y, na.rm=TRUE))/(sd(y,na.rm=TRUE))}
#normed <- apply(data,2, z_score_function)
#dataNormed <- data.frame(normed)

#normalization <- function(y) {
#return ((y - min(y)) / (max(y) - min(y)))
#}
# Min-Max Normalization
#data$ram <- (data$ram - min(data$ram)) / (max(data$ram) - min(data$ram))
#data$px_height <- (data$px_height - min(data$px_height)) / (max(data$px_height) - min(data$px_height))
#data$px_width <- (data$px_width - min(data$px_width)) / (max(data$px_width) - min(data$px_width))
#data$battery_power <- (data$battery_power - min(data$battery_power)) / (max(data$battery_power) - min(data$battery_power))


# Declare to R which variables are numeric and which are categorical/nominal to R

cols_to_factors <- c('blue','dual_sim','four_g','three_g','touch_screen','wifi')
dataToModel <- data.frame(lapply(data[,cols_to_factors],as.factor))
dataToModel <- cbind(data[,!colnames(data)%in%cols_to_factors],dataToModel)
rm(cols_to_factors)
## Reordering the columns
dataToModel <- dataToModel[,c(1,16,2,17,3,18,4:14,19,20,21,15)]

## Variable to coerce to integer
dataToModel$n_cores <- as.integer(dataToModel$n_cores)

dataToModel$price_range<-as.factor(dataToModel$price_range)

#IDs
dataToModel<-cbind(c(1:nrow(dataToModel)),dataToModel)
colnames(dataToModel)[1]<-"id"
str(dataToModel)


#MOdel Neural Networks

library(neuralnet)
library(dplyr)

# Make training and validation data
set.seed(123)
train <- sample(nrow(dataToModel), nrow(dataToModel)*0.7)
test <- seq(nrow(dataToModel))[-train]
train_N <- dataToModel[train,]
test_N <- dataToModel[test,]

# Binarize the categorical output
train_N <- cbind(train_N, train_N$price_range == '0')
train_N <- cbind(train_N, train_N$price_range == '1')
train_N <- cbind(train_N, train_N$price_range == '2')
train_N <- cbind(train_N, train_N$price_range == '3')
names(train_N)[23:26] <- c('level_0', 'level_1', 'level_2','level_3')

# Fit model
nn <- neuralnet(
   level_0 + level_1 + level_2+ level_3 ~ ram+px_height+px_width+battery_power,
  data=train_N, hidden = 4,lifesign = "full")
print(nn)
plot(nn)
comp <- compute(nn, test_N[,-22])
pred.weights <- comp$net.result
idx <- apply(pred.weights,1, which.max)
idx
pred <- c('0','1','2','3')[idx]
pred
table(pred, test_N$price_range)

accuracy_NN<-sum(pred==test_N$price_range)/nrow(test_N)
accuracy_NN
```

Comment: You have shared a lot of code. Please try to identify the problem and share a **minimal** example illustrating your problem. We don't have your Excel file, so we don't need to see your code reading in the data unless you think that's where the problem is. And transforming the data - if the transformations work, you do not need to show us the code. Check that they work as expected, if so remove that code from the question. Do show us a little bit of sample data (5-10 rows) right before you fit the model, where the problem is. Don't show us 50+ lines of code before the problem.

Comment: I have not use the `neuralnet` package, but looking at the documentation they give an example of multiclass classification, and it does **not** use several binary columns as the target, it uses a single column of class `factor`. So that is the first thing I would try to see if it fixes the problem. From `?neuralnet`, *`# Multiclass classification`
`nn <- neuralnet(Species ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris, linear.output = FALSE)`*